# Is the capybara-screenshot host URL configurable?

Tags: rspec, capybara, screenshot

in lib/capybara-screenshot/rspec/html_link_reporter.rb, the prefix of the url is configured as :

```
url = URI.escape("file://#{path}")
```

..which produces this:

```
file:///var/lib/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp/tmp/Pelican-CI/196/screenshot_2019-07-11-15-29-02.049.html
```

..it would be preferred to be:

```
http://jenkins:8080/project1/build8/something.jpg
```

which could be accomplished using:

```
<capybara.asset_host>/<capybara.save_path>
```

Is capybara-screenshot's url prefix attribute configurable via a .yml file?

I could find nothing in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not, you'd either have to monkeypatch the current method or, better yet, write your own custom formatter - https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot/blob/master/lib/capybara-screenshot/rspec.rb#L19